# How can I do row grouping in rdlc

Tags: winforms, reporting-services, rdlc

I have this scenario:

AccountType..| Accounts..| Amount

Capital...........| b/f.............|.......200

PL..................| Sales........|.......150

PL..................| Expense...|..... -100

PL.................| Wages.......|..... -20

The PL accounts are supposed to be grouped into a single row called profit.

So far I am ending up with this:

Capital............................................

......................| b/f.............|.......200

......................| Profit........|.......150

......................| Profit........|..... -100

......................| Profit.........|..... -20

I need to end up with a report like this:

Capital.........................................

......................| b/f..........|........200

......................| Profit......|..........30

Glad to hear about possibilities

Comment: Have you tried grouping by Accounts in the row group properties?

Comment: @StevenWhite I think that is the problem, he is still grouping by Accounts. Hannington, you need to group by AccountType not Accounts